# Animate items while opening bottom Sheet in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Please I want to animate the items in my bottom sheet as the bottom sheet opens. I want the item to slowly enlarge as the user drags open the bottom sheet and the texts to fade in as the sheet opens. I also want the reverse to happen when the bottom sheet closes i .e The item in the sheet shrinks and the texts slowly fades out. Something similar to the gif attached

[What I'm trying to achieve(Source: Youtube music.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKZi0.gif)

Comment: This is type of animation. You know how to set up page route animations??

Comment: yeah, I do, can I use it to get this result